# Hiker's Cabin Mystery | Pt. VI

Tags: cipher

**The only part that doesn't have an answer yet is Part II! Chop, chop!**

You finally are able to get out of the airport after quickly solving the mystery. You are becoming quite the detective! Only...

---

you find another clue hidden in your suitcase after you arrive at your dwelling. That clever little guy!
[image: clue page]
Apparently, solving this puzzle will lead you to him. You thought he was in Chad, but it looks like he has hidden somewhere else. You'd better get cracking!

Comment: Could you provide a transcript? Copying ciphertext characters out by hand does not add to the fun or the challenge of solving a puzzle...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan u can use OCR :)

Comment: I used an extremely advanced neural network designed by a lengthy evolutionary algorithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should go to

> Switzerland.

The message

> consists entirely of even-length "words", composed of a repertoire of only 22 distinct pairs of letters. Replacing each of these with a unique letter and solving as a simple-substitution cipher yields: IF YOU HAVE FINALLY RECOVERED THIS NOTE IT MEANS THAT THE SITUATION IS GRAVER THAN I COULD POSSIBLY HAVE IMAGINED GO TO SWITZERLAND THAT IS WHERE I WILL BE HIDING YOU WILL FIND MORE CLUES THERE.

Comment: This is incredible work! Very well done, once again!

Comment: (I will wait to accept it so you can get some upvotes.)

Comment: That's fine; accept as soon or as late as you please.

Comment: Do you want to take a shot at Part II again? You're really close! (I feel like I'm just advertising, at this point :P)

Comment: Well, I found an error in my calculations that changes my answer slightly. I assume it's wronger than that, though.